# Cannot install packages from scratch anymore on MacOS after OS update

Tags: r, macos

I know this is a reoccurring issue but all tips I have found did not apply to me.

I do have Xcode command line tools installed, and I also installed goFortran, see: https://mac.r-project.org/tools/
I also did remove the only https checkmark in the RStudio settings for packages.

Currently, I am trying to install a package called "estimatr" but I also tried others. Whenever I have to install from source I get the following error:

```
22 warnings generated. clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/opt/R/arm64/lib -o estimatr.so RcppExports.o horvitz_thompson_variance.o lm_robust_helper.o naomit.o
    -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.2.0/11.0.0 -L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lemutls_w -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation 
ld: warning: -single_module is obsolete 
ld: warning: -multiply_defined is obsolete 
ld: warning: search path '/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.2.0/11.0.0' not found 
ld: warning: search path '/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib' not found 
ld: library 'gfortran' not found 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 
make: *** [estimatr.so] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘estimatr’
* removing ‘/Users/myname/Library/R/arm64/4.1/library/estimatr’
```

I wonder what I could do?

Here is my sessioninfo()

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 14.0

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_2.4.2 usethis_2.2.2 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] prettyunits_1.2.0 ps_1.7.5          crayon_1.5.2      R6_2.5.1          lifecycle_1.0.3   magrittr_2.0.3   
 [7] rlang_1.1.1       cachem_1.0.6      cli_3.6.1         remotes_2.4.2.1   rstudioapi_0.13   fs_1.6.3         
[13] callr_3.7.3       vctrs_0.6.4       ellipsis_0.3.2    tools_4.1.1       glue_1.6.2        purrr_1.0.2      
[19] pkgload_1.3.3     processx_3.8.2    fastmap_1.1.0     compiler_4.1.1    pkgbuild_1.4.2    sessioninfo_1.2.2
[25] memoise_2.0.1
```

Anything I could try to solve this issue?

Comment: I **strongly** recommend installing R on macOS via [rig](https://github.com/r-lib/rig), which avoids all of these problems. No need to install gfortran manually, either (but no harm if you have already installed it).

Comment: I didn't even think abut installing it newly again but at this point why not (trying to solve this for days now)

Comment: @KonradRudolph well I did install using rig and also installed studio new but the problem just now stretches to even more package installations. Can't even install devtools anymore...

Comment: Can you update your post with a precise error message for ‘devtools’? Your question currently also shows an outdated R version, be sure to use an up to date version. Lastly, it might help to run this directly in R, outside of RStudio.

Comment: From all I have seen now, it seems like my R (that I installed brand new) is still "outdated"? And it seems like it doesn't "find" or use the gfortran. And yes, I can try this in "base R" instead of RStudio but I always work in RStudio so it should work again. Thanks!

Comment: As you can see in the output you posted, your version of R is 2 years old. R's current version is 4.3.1.

Comment: Two warnings of the log tell that the paths to gcc and gfortran are not found. You could try `which gcc` and `which gfortran` in the terminal. They will give you the paths that you can use in CC and CF respectively in Makevars. For example, I have `CC=/usr/bin/gcc` in my `~/.R/Makevars`

Comment: Jeah, somehow using rig already gives me errors, when trying to install R 4.3.1. (even though rig list already shows the newer one) rig add
[INFO] Running `sudo` for adding new R versions. This might need your password.
[INFO] arm64-R-4.3.1-arm64.pkg is cached at /tmp/rig/arm64-R-4.3.1-arm64.pkg
[INFO] Running installer
[INFO] > installer: Package name is R 4.3.1 for macOS (ARM64)
[INFO] > installer: Installing at base path /
[INFO] > installer: The install failed. [ERROR] command ["arch", "-arm64", "installer", "-pkg", "/tmp/rig/uAiwgjGCTO.pkg", "-target", "/"] exited with code 1

Comment: @DuccioA That is definitely not necessary with a correct installation of R on macOS. It would be a hacky workaround that just hides the problems rather than fixing them.

Comment: which gcc gives /usr/bin/gcc but gfortran not found - which is weird as I installed it earlier and @Konrad said I don't need it if I use the rig. What is a "~/.R/Makevars" ?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sure tweaking Makevars is a workaround but the problems are there. There are other ways of fixing the paths and to be fair I am not an expert. I, too, might give `rig` a try.

Comment: @canIchangethis Nevermind Makevars, but it looks like the installation has problems in finding the gcc and gfortran compilers and it is usually a problem of paths. There are several solutions to that, `rig` might be one.

Comment: @DuccioA Right, “the problems are there”. So *the problems need to be solved!* There’s no way around that. And tweaking the Makevars file categorically doesn’t solve the problems.

Comment: So, after a lot of tweaking I managed to update R using rig. Now I just have to make the new version the default. Thanks so much for your help!